# Copying value of single variable from Host to Device variable

Tags: c++, c, variables, cuda, copying

I am wondering how to properly copy value of host variable directly to device variable

I tried to use cudaMemcpy but without any special results. I was getting only garbage or nothing.

```
Pixel_GPU* Device_Array{};
//__device__ size_t size{};
size_t size{};
cudaMalloc((void**)& Device_Array, global_size * sizeof(Pixel_GPU));
cudaMalloc((void**) size, sizeof(size_t));
cudaMemset(&size, 0, sizeof(size_t));

cudaMemcpy(Device_Array, Host_Array, global_size * sizeof(Pixel_GPU), HostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(&size, &global_size, sizeof(size_t), HostToDevice);
_STD cout << global_size << NEW_LINE;
Show_Device_Variables <<<2, 1>>>(&size);

cudaFree(&size);
cudaFree(Device_Array);

free(Host_Array);
```

For instance: global_size may have size upon to 1 000 000 . Size_t is able to take it on, but the size of "size" (device array size) is still uninitialized

Comment: did you intialize the host array? You must do it before call Memcpy...

Comment: The sensible way to pass a scalar quantity is by value, not using `cudaMalloc` at all.  You might want to study a basic CUDA sample code like `vectorAdd`.

Comment: Thanks guys for your advice's. I am so green in this matter but I learn it every day and I try to write a good cuda code. Thanks once again

Comment: Yes yes I initialized HostArray earlier, this is only a snippet from my whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the (indeterminate) value of `size` reinterpreted as a pointer to `cudaMalloc`.
This is not a good idea; CUDA is probably going to write the address of its freshly allocated device memory in some arbitrary place.
If you're lucky, it crashes, but if you're unlucky it might just seem like nothing happened.

All `cudaMalloc` calls follow the same pattern:

```
T* p;  // This is going to be a device pointer.
cudaMalloc((void**) &p, ... // Pass the address of the pointer.
```

so you should have

```
size_t* size{};
cudaMalloc((void**) &size, sizeof(size_t));
cudaMemset(size, 0, sizeof(size_t));
// ...
cudaMemcpy(size, &global_size, sizeof(size_t), HostToDevice);
Show_Device_Variables <<<2, 1>>>(size);

cudaFree(size);
```